# Synchronize Multiple Anaconda Installations

Tags: sync, anaconda, cross-platform

I am a dual boot user, I use Ubuntu18.04 and Windows 10. I also have a parrot Linux running in VM inside ubuntu. Very Obviously I have a problem with tools sync across these platforms.

I have an ongoing demand in this regard. I want to sync all my anaconda installations i.e. I need an option to enlist and trigger my anaconda packages of windows to get automatically installed in Ubuntu or vice versa.

I have searched a bit on the internet, but didn't find something related. Any way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you start using [conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html).
Additionally using a git repository to keep track of your different environment specifications wouldn't hurt.
Alternatively as it's all one machine you could setup a location that is accessible to both Windows and Linux and store the environment specification files there.

## Create environment on Windows and re-create it on Linux

### Windows

In Windows you could for example create an environment with python 3.7, pandas and numpy and plotly:

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.7 pandas numpy plotly
```

Then you would export that environment to a `.yml` file:

```
conda activate myenv
conda env export > myenv.yml
```

### Linux

Now on Linux you can create the same environment by using that `.yml` file.

```bsh
conda env create -f myenv.yml
```

You could place that `.yml` file in git and sync it easily between the different OS'es.

## Updating an environment

### Linux

Now say you've added a package or two when in Linux to `myenv`:

```bsh
conda activate myenv
conda install matplotlib beautifulsoup4
```

You need to re-export that environment to a new specification `.yml` file with:

```bsh
conda activate myenv
conda env export > myenv.yml
```

### Windows

Now on Windows you can get that newly created `myenv.yml` and use it to sync up the Windows conda environment:

```
conda activate myenv
conda env update -f myenv.yml --prune
```

Comment: Thanks Lindestøkke for this suggestion. I didn't really think this way of sharing my configurations using github, But it could be easier if this could be automated than bothering to use the commands using some tool. Currently, I would be using dropbox to sync my configuration file in your suggested way. But a more robust automation is still sought. Also nam mapping the correct env in case of multiple env is going to be a trouble.

Comment: All these commands can be automated to be run every n-minutes, resulting in an automated solution. As you have two different OS'es I don't think there's another way. You can't simply share the library files directly as they are different per OS.
Also, if keeping track of different environments via "name mapping" is too difficult, one has to wonder if your current set-up is too complex.

Comment: "There is no other way" - I feel there should be, I use VS Code, and have the same problem with configuration setup, there is an extension to do it on vs code with one click [settings-sync](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync). Was looking for something alike. Thanks for your solution though. And I have multiple environments for professional and personal space and sub-usecase for them as well. Which is why I am looking for a sync-soultion.

Comment: I don't the comparison between settings of an application with a whole package manager is fair. The latter is far more complex. If you find something though, I look forward to see it as an answer.

Comment: Sure. Just to be accurate, not settings actually, it takes up all your extenstions in vs code. Also I get your point. But my trouble is to automate syncing and reproducing that yml only. rest(installation) is easy.Again thanks for your method.